# Add parameters from variable to extract json data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using an API that pulls Airport information data and prints the data in the form of a json.

I am using json_decode() to store this json into an array (I am using the ,true)

I have a loop that checks the number of arriving aircraft and it succeeds because if there were 15 arrivals it could print out a string of text 15 times. However, when decoding the json I need to use parameters to get to the info. For example, if I want to get to how many arrivals, I will need to do like this:

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode($json_file, true);
print_r($jsonDecode['AirportBoardsResult']['arrivals']['num_flights']);
```

This gives out how many arrivals there are and the result can be placed into a variable like this:

```
$arrivals = $jsonDecode['AirportBoardsResult']['arrivals']['num_flights'];
```

If I print that, it will print the correct integer.
However, to get the flightnumber of the first flight, you need to do it like this:

```
$flightnumber = $jsonDecode['AirportBoardsResult']['arrivals']['flights']['0']['ident'];
```

Where '0' is the first flight and '1' is the second etc...
I tried to create a for loop to get the flightnumber of all the arrivals, here's the code:

```
$initialCode = $jsonDecode['AirportBoardsResult']['arrivals']['flights'];

for($arrivalInt = $arrivals; $arrivalInt > 0; $arrivalInt--) {
    $flightnumbers = $initialCode . $arrivalInt . 'ident';
    echo $flightnumbers;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I tried to use array_push to add the $arrivalInt and the 'ident' at the end but nope. I tried to do it like this:

```
for($arrivalInt = $arrivals; $arrivalInt > 0; $arrivalInt--) {
    $flightnumbers = $initialCode . "[" . "'" . $arrivalInt . "'" . "]" . "[" . "'" . "ident" . "'" . "]";
    echo $flightnumbers;
}
```

But same result :( The result I get is just the echo of $initialCode.

Basically I just want to add the parameters to the end of the json_decode.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I think you miss parameters

Comment: $arrivals = $jsonDecode['AirportBoardsResult']['arrivals']['flights'];

Comment: I want to add the parameters ['$arrivalInt'] to the end of the $jsonDecode, basically adding data from a variable or integer into the end of the $jsonDecode

Comment: Oh, I used $initialCode for that since that is necessary for the data pulling. Then I tried to add to this $initialCode which has a json_decode in it.

Comment: This is much simpler than you make it out to be. Just use `foreach($initialCode as $flight) {$flightnumber = $flight['ident']; echo $flightnumber;}`

Comment: @jh1711 I feel stupid for not realizing that, thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jh1711 for the answer!

I should've used a foreach loop instead, like this:

```
foreach($initialCode as $flight) {
  $flightnumber = $flight['ident'];
  echo $flightnumber;
}
```